# Writing at the top of the CSV file (or alternatively, how to reverse one)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, append, reverse

I need to append data to a CSV file containing monthly records provided by a third party that's in an illogical order, meaning the newest records are at the top. I need to add a new line every month, but I haven't found a way to append at the top, nor to cleverly reverse it.

One way, I realize, would be to loop the lines in reverse order and write to a new file, but that seems stupid. Surely there must be a smarter answer.

Is there?

Comment: Do you have a time stamp field for each record? If so, you can concatenate or append, then re-sort... sorry. You don't want to do that, I reread your question. Do you also maintain the code that reads the file? You could have it read from the end of a chronologically sorted CSV data file... urg ;o) too.

Comment: Yeah, I do maintain. I'll have to do something like that if other solutions don't exist. Thanks. :-)